# Javascript window.open height will not go as tall as I set, why?

Tags: javascript, window

JavaScript window.open height will not go as tall as I set, why?

I am using FF, IE, Chrome, and using this function.

```
function open_win3(zoom) {
New_Win3 =window.open(zoom,"_blank","width=550,height=1970,scrollbars=0,menubar=0");
}
var zoom = "/zoom.asp"
```

Will the height of the new window opened by JavaScript only be as tall as the monitor itself is tall?

Chrome also added scroll bars, when clearly scrollbars are negative, but I got around that by using

```
<style type="text/css">
    body { overflow: hidden; }
</style>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's 2012. All of your problems could be solved by using an HTML pop-up (i.e. lightbox) rather than an old-school popup window.

Comment: @Utkanos, Actually no that doesn't solve the OP's problem, even in 2012.

Comment: If I do switch to a div layer - just a little time involved. I suppose the browser's won't be able to restrict whatever height we give it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open#Note_on_position_and_dimension_error_correction) :

> Requested position and requested dimension values in the features list
>   will not be honored and will be corrected if any of such requested
>   value does not allow the entire browser window to be rendered within
>   the work area for applications of the user's operating system. No part
>   of the new window can be initially positioned offscreen. This is by
>   default in all Mozilla-based browser releases.

As many other features regarding window.open, this can be easily explained as a security : the browser must prevent the user from not understanding he's looking at a new browser window, or having difficulties closing it.

Comment: Is Chrome part of Mozilla?  OR your just suggesting it is most likely with all browsers it is not a possibility to have a new window open below the fold?

Comment: As with most security features, they're clearly described in Mozilla but the same in Chrome, Safari and Firefox (and often IE).